# How to make this class valid for the xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, xhtml

How to find the Xpath for this?

```
<div class="_7UhW9   xLCgt       qyrsm        h_zdq     fDxYl    T0kll ">Continue as dsfshhfh</div>
```

I tried this but this is not working. Class is not getting the actual results.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class="_7UhW9   xLCgt       qyrsm        h_zdq     fDxYl    T0kll "]").click()
```

Comment: That name looks like an encoded class, which would be why. It most likely is displayed differently on each page load.

Comment: Is the code that you tried actually what you've posted in the question as it's not syntactically correct, you're missing a " at the end just before the .click

Comment: @StephenK no actually. It was a mistake

Comment: Do you need to select the `div` element by all those class tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Your class name attribute must be dynamic.Try the following xpath to click()

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'Continue as')]").click()
```

Comment: can you please explain this :contains(.,'Continue as')

Comment: It will search the substring inside your element tag

Comment: What error are you getting.can you post your error log in your original post

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(.,'Continue as')]"}